# Neighborhood for an element with a topology generated from the basis

Tags: general-topology

Consider the set X={w,x,y,z} with the topology generated from the basis B={X,$\emptyset$,{w,x},{w},{y}} what would the neighborhoods for the element $y\in X$ be?

Updated: One topology generated would be {X,$\emptyset$,{w},{y},{w,x},{w,x,y},{w,y}}. Then, the neighborhoods for element $y\in X$ would be {w,x},{w,y} and {y}.

Are these neighborhoods correct and would there be others?

Comment: What is the definition of neighbourhood in use? Is a neighbourhood required to be open?

Comment: There is a neighborhood, N, of the point y if there exists an open set U such that $y \in U \subseteq N$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this topology, the set $\{y\}$ is open. Thus, any subset of $X$ containing $y$ is a neighbourhood of $y$ in your definition.